# unrecognized selector with UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current().section(for:collationStringSelector:#selector(getter: UIPreviewAction.title))

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalizedcollation, uipreviewaction

This code I use with my indexing feature on a table view is generating a runtime error:

```
let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current()

sectionNumber = collation.section(for: tssContact, collationStringSelector: #selector(getter: UIPreviewAction.title))
```

The error occurs in the second line in my code above.  The error says:

> 2017-10-03 01:41:40.997296-0500 MailToText[6504:13026014]
>   -[MailToText.TSSContact title]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000481090 2017-10-03 01:41:41.020775-0500
>   MailToText[6504:13026014] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[MailToText.TSSContact title]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x604000481090'

How do I fix this.  It was working before I went to Swift 4 and made the recommended adjustments to settings going to Xcode 9.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I looked at the error message where it says [MailToText.TSSContact title] and found TSSContact.title in my project, and put "@objc" next to "var title" in the class TSSContact.

That fixed it.